# How to sort python unittest discover tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, multiplatform, python-unittest

I created my bunch of Python tests using the Python `unittest` format.

Now I'm able to run them with

```
python -m unittest discover -s TestDirectory -p '*.py' -v
```

I finds them all, and runs them.

Now there's a subtle difference whether I run the tests on Windows, or on Linux. Indeed, on Windows the tests are run in alphabetical order, whereas on Linux the tests are run in no apparent human specific discoverable order, even if always the same.

The trouble is I relied on the first two letters of the test file to sort the order of execution of the tests. Not that they have to be run in a specific order, but to have some kind of *informational* tests, showing version data in their output to appear first in the test run log.

Is there something I can do to run the tests also in alphabetical order on Linux?

Comment: have you try nosetests? i wonder running nosetests directly will make a difference. I don't use discover from unittest because nosetests can do that pretty well. have you tried that?

Comment: Just tried. Looks like tests are sorted on Linux. Thanks. But I'd like to avoid forcing developers to install nose, and just use plain python with integrated `unittest`.

Comment: When I run this for my unit tests under Linux, it sorts them in the following order: first by file or directory name, subordered by class name, subordered by test (method) name. The thing is, when running the tests, the test *names* are shown first, which is only the last subsubordering, and does not appear with any logical ordering. I just want to check that your apparent non-ordering is actually the above file/directory - class - method ordering?

Comment: The tests are discovered in whatever order os.listdir returns them which is not deterministic.  They have fixed the problem in Python 3.2+ which won't help most of us yet, but you could monkey patch the same change  http://bugs.python.org/issue16709

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I imagine that one thing you could do is override the TestSuite class to add a sort function.  Then you can call the sort function before calling the unittest run function.  So, in an 'AllTests.py' script, you could add something like this:

```
class SortableSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    def sort(self):
        self._tests.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: x._testMethodName < y._testMethodName)
    def run(self,testResult):
        #or if you don't want to run a sort() function, you can override the run
        #function to automatically sort.
        self._tests.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: x._testMethodName < y._testMethodName)
        return unittest.TestSuite.run(self,testResult)

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
loader.suiteClass = SortableSuite
suite = loader.loadTestFromTestCases(collectedTests)
suite.sort()
suite.run(defaultTestResult())
```